# Spring jpa properties javax or jakarta?

Tags: spring, jpa, javax-validation, jakarta-validation

I am using Spring Boot 3.1. Into Applcation.yml spring: jpa: properties: javax: Persistence: Validation: mode:none --otherwise spring: jpa: properties: jakarta: Persistence: Validation: mode:none --which one should i use?

which one should i use

Comment: Please reformat your question, it is very difficult to read and understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring 6 retired javax packages and completely moved to jakarta packages.

That also includes Tomcat 10, it will not work with javax packages.

In order to run Spring boot 3, you will need to migrate all dependencies from javax to jakarta and also minimal JDK for Spring Boot 3 is JDK17.